# Switch from Ruby to JRuby at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

Is there a way I can switch to jruby on the fly as I execute code? This seems rather unrealistic so far, but I was wondering it it's possible.

My use case is the following: I built a gem that does a variety of things, among them is connecting to database for which I need Java/jruby. This is the only instance in which I need jRuby, and I am loading this gem into my MRI rails to do all of things which is accomplishes successfully, except when I want to run the code that uses jRuby. I switch to jRuby using rvm from the command line but from there I have no idea how to make my code pick up the change. Any ideas? I understand this might not be very clear so please ask me questions.

Comment: How exactly did you "switch" to jruby?

Comment: rvm from the command line. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: So, what is the problem? now you are running on JRuby, why do you need to switch back?

Comment: Maybe you can spawn a separate jruby process to do all that work?

Comment: @MxyL is that possible from within an MRI process?

Comment: @n_x_l Sure, you can spawn and manage processes using the `Process` module.

Comment: @MxyL how can I spawn a process from MRI that is a jRuby process?